# Program to work out an age gives error about a getset_descriptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, integer, typeerror

I am trying to write a very simple Python program to work out someone's age and I think, in theory, it should work however every time I try to run it, it throws this error:

```
What year were you born in? 2005
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'getset_descriptor' and 'int'
```

I have tried turning `datetime.year` and `(year)`  (same things) in to integers. It worked but didn't make a difference as the both are already integers. This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
year = datetime.year
born = input("What year were you born in?")
born = int(born)
end = year - born
print(end)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`year = datetime.year` does not give you the current year. It gives you an unbound [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) instead (the `getset_descriptor` in your error):

```
>>> datetime.year
<attribute 'year' of 'datetime.date' objects>
>>> type(datetime.year)
<class 'getset_descriptor'>
>>> datetime.year - 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'getset_descriptor' and 'int'
```

Don't worry too much about the exact type of object here, that's just an implementation detail needed to make instances of a built-in immutable type like `datetime` work. It just means you don't have an *instance* of the `datetime` type, so there is no `year` value for that instance either.

If you want the current year, use `datetime.now().year`:

```
year = datetime.now().year
```

[`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) gives you a `datetime` *instance*, the one representing the current time and date. That instance has a valid `year` attribute.

You could also use [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) of course:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 31, 14, 58, 14, 994030)
>>> datetime.now().year
2016
>>> date.today().year
2016
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. What is a getset_descriptor?

Comment: I do like you answer though, there are only some parts that I don't understand.

Comment: @Kiran: it is an internal object on some Python built-in types that are defined in C, where those objects don't have a `__dict__` attribute on the instances. In other words, a specialist implementation detail you don't normally need to worry about.