# Python cant pickle getset_descriptor

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle, deep-copy

I was trying something with `types.MappingProxyType`:

```py
class MyClass:
    l = [1, 2]

proxy = MyClass.__dict__
```

Then I wanted to extract dictionary from this Proxy:

```py
d = proxy.copy()

print(type(d))
#<class 'dict'>
```

Then I wanted to append something to list value of `d`:

```py
d["l"].append(3)
```

But this also affects `proxy` (for sure):

```py
>>> print(proxy["l"])
[1, 2, 3]
```

I wanted to not affect our `proxy`, so I tried using `copy.deepcopy`:

```py
import copy

dict_2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
```

And it gived an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\istihza.py", line 18, in <module>
    dict_2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle getset_descriptor objects
```

I know that the copy module is trying to use functions which are used by pickle module for copying.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

> Classes can use the same interfaces to control copying that they use
>   to control pickling. See the description of module pickle for
>   information on these methods. In fact, the copy module uses the
>   registered pickle functions from the copyreg module.

The problem is that, type of `d` is `dict`. And we can deepcopy dicts:

```py
copy.deepcopy({"this":["is", "a", "dict"]})
```

So if type of `d` is `dict`, why I cant deepcopy it? Or is the type of `d` is not really dict and is it only a hack in the Python?

Comment: What does this have to do with pickle, which is mentioned in the title and as a tag?

Comment: @myke, look at the error traceback

Comment: @myke Also look at the [documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) please : "Classes can use the same interfaces to control copying that they use to control pickling. See the description of module pickle for information on these methods. In fact, the copy module uses the registered pickle functions from the copyreg module."

Comment: Does this help? [Program to work out an age gives error about a getset_descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409301/program-to-work-out-an-age-gives-error-about-a-getset-descriptor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d` is indeed a dictionary.  The issue you are running into is that pickle cannot serialize methods and attributes of classes independent of the class.  When you look at the contents of `d` you see:

```py
{'__module__': '__main__',
 'l': [1, 2, 3],
 '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
 '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
 '__doc__': None}
```

The values for `__dict__` and `__weakref__` are attributes of the `MyClass` object.  You cannot serialize these without **also** serializing `MyClass`.

Furthermore, if you check the type of each of these, you can see this is where the error you are seeing arises from:

```py
type(d['__dict__']), type(d['__weakref__'])
# returns:
(getset_descriptor, getset_descriptor)
```